# Why does this not pull any data?

Tags: sql, db2

The following snippet is a join on multiple tables.  I need to display all order number, customer name, product name, price and quantity ordered from anyone from Australia.  I'm getting table headings but no rows.  Is there something wrong with this?

```
SELECT 
      "order".orderno AS ord, 
      customer.cname, 
      product.prodname, 
      customer.country_code, 
      orderdetl.price, 
      orderdetl.qty, 
      country.country_code
    FROM 
      prema01.country, 
      prema01.customer, 
      prema01."order", 
      prema01.orderdetl, 
      prema01.product
    WHERE 
      customer.country_code = 'AUS'
```

I've changed the code, verified there is data in the tables and it still comes out blank.
I am completely stumped.

```
SELECT O.ORDERNO, C.CNAME, PN.PRODNAME, ODT.PRICE, ODT.QTY, ODT.QTY * PN.PRODSELL AS TOTAL
FROM prema01.ORDER O, prema01.CUSTOMER C, prema01.ORDERDETL ODT, prema01.PRODUCT PN, prema01.COUNTRY CT
WHERE CT.COUNTRY_NAME = 'Australia' 
AND C.COUNTRY_CODE = CT.COUNTRY_CODE 
AND C.CUSTNO = O.CUSTNO 
AND O.ORDERNO = ODT.ORDERNO 
AND PN.PRODNO = ODT.PRODNO AND O.ORDERNO <= 60
ORDER BY TOTAL DESC;
```

forgot to add the change.  the tables have data in them, i've physically verified that.

Comment: What SQL is this? it looks very wrong. Is Prem a table? Can decribe what tables you have and what columns they have please.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You should have JOIN clauses.

Comment: its DB2, i'm using Postgre to test my code since iNagivators connection to my school is trash.

Comment: Without JOIN clauses DB2 performs a cartesian join; every row in every table is joined against every row in every other table. Show us the result of `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 1=0` for every tableName in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you need some join conditions e.g.

```
Select
  r.country_code,
  c.cname
From
  prema01.country r
    inner join
  prema01.customer c
    on r.country_code = c.country_code
```

You need to build up the relationships with the other tables in a similar way.

Also, are you sure your tables have any data in them. Does

```
Select
  Count(*)
From
  prema01.country
```

return anything? How about

```
Select
  Count(*)
From
  prema01.customer
Where
  country_code = 'AUS'
```

?

Comment: The first count query or the second?

Comment: 2 for the 1st query, 8 for the 2nd.

Comment: Have you tried putting the explicit join conditions in? If So I'd build in one table at a time until you find the one that breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I was looking for 'Australia' while I have 'AUSTRALIA' in my country table.  thanks for the help